# Problems with slider in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, sliders

I have one problem, I am working with **angularJS**, but i am using sliders by other in a library. The sliders start with `$(document).ready(`...

The page is within a **routeprovider** and is divided into two other parts that turn on and off with `ng-show`. If the first one is the slider starts, no problem.

However, if you first load the other and pressing the button of an active slider that did not load well (I guess `$(document).ready` no longer works).

Any solutions?

Answer (score 4):

This is very tough to answer without some examples, but my guess is that since you're using full-blown jQuery in addition to angular, its scope is getting clobbered when done out of order. Your best bet is to use an angular-based slider, or create one using angular. Crossing the js-framework streams rarely ends well.